# Converting a string to a number in R

Tags: r

I'm having trouble with simply writing a function that turns a string representation of a number into a decimal representation. To boil the issue down to essentials, consider the following function:

```
   f <- function(x) {
      y <- as.numeric(x)
      return(y)
   }
```

When I apply this function to the string "47.418" I get back 47.42, but what I want to get back is 47.418. It seems like the return value is being rounded for some reason.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe include a more extensive code sample.

Answer (score 3):

You have done something to your print options. I get no rounding:

```
> f <- function(x) { y <- as.numeric(x); return(y) }
> f(47.418)
[1] 47.418

?options
```

The default value for digits is 7:

```
> options("digits")
$digits
[1] 7
```

Further questions should be accompanied by `dput()` on the object in question.

Comment: I get 7 for options("digits"), and I get 47.418 for dput(f("47.418"))